# On Frattinian p-groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

A $p$-group $G$ is called *Frattinian* if $Z(M)$ is not equal to $Z(G)$ for all maximal subgroups $M$ of $G$; and $(G, Z(G))$ is called a *Camina pair* if $xZ(G)$ is contained in the conjugacy class of $x$ for all $x \in G \setminus Z(G)$.

Is there example of Frattinian $p$-group $G$ of class greater than $2$, where $p$ is an odd prime, such that $(G, Z(G))$ is a Camina pair?

Comment: I guess all groups in your question are finite.

Comment: This was clearly meant to clarify and re-ask your other question, which I have deleted so there is no redundancy, but next time please just edit the question instead of re-asking in another question.

Answer (score 5):

Let $G$ be the group defined by the presentation
$$ G = \langle \, a, c \mid a^{p^n}=c^{p^{n+1}} = 1, \; c^a = c^{1+p} \, 
       \rangle, $$
where $p$ is an odd prime. ($G$ is the semidirect product of the normal cyclic subgroup $\langle c \rangle $ of order $p^{n+1}$ and the $p$-Sylow of its automorphism group.)
Then:

- $\mathbf{Z}(G) = \langle c^{p^n} \rangle$ has order $p$ and $(G, \mathbf{Z}(G) )$ is a Camina pair.
- The Frattini subgroup of $G$ is $\Phi(G) = G^p G'= \langle a^p, c^p \rangle$, and thus $G$ has $p+1$ maximal subgroups. All these have a center of order $p^2$. (One center is of type $C_p\times C_p$, and the others of type $C_{p^2}$.)
- $G$ has nilpotency class $n+1$.

Comment: What is the order of G?

Comment: @Rohit: $p^{2n+1}$.

Comment: For this group $G$, can $[g,G]$ for all $g\in G$ form subgroup?

Comment: @Rohit: That seems to be the case, but I did not check formally. However, that shouldn't be too difficult.